# How do I build my project with Ant

Tags: java, ant

I created a project in Eclipse that had some source folder as src and output folder as bin.

Now I want to move this to Ant. How to get up to speed while doing this?

I have two main classes that I require in this project.

In my src/..main/ package I also have JUnit testcase class.

How do I migrate to using Ant as fast as I could?

Comment: [Ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing to *migrate*. You add a `build.xml` to tell Ant where things are located just like you did in Eclipse. In fact, Eclipse gives you the ability to generate an Ant build.xml file right from Eclipse.

- Right click on the project.
- Select "Export". This brings up a Select dialog box
- Open "General" and click "Ant Buildfiles"

This will generate an Ant build.xml file for your project.

Now, read up on [Ant](http://ant.apache.org). It's something all Java developers should know.